# Why does my attempt to scrape the value of a text element return zero?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am scraping a website with a "load more" button. I need to extract the underlined number in yellow, but I get 0.

[image]

Here is [the website](https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements). How can I extract the needed information?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from parsel import Selector
from scrapy.selector import Selector 
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
nexturl = 'https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements'
response = requests.get(nexturl)
sel = Selector(response)
nbPages = sel.xpath('//div[@class="_1Nm7X TkLPj"]/text()').extract() 
print(nbPages)
```

Comment: The website shows zero briefly upon loading. The value is apparently updated via an ajax call. Set a delay in your script, or watch for a value change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get total "annonces" count,  you need to to simulate XHR. For me it works like below, but you can try to modify it (remove unnecessary headers, prettify `data`, etc...):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.tayara.tn',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = '{"query":"query ListingsPage($page: Page, $filter: SearchFilter, $sortBy: SortOrder) {\\n  listings: searchAds(page: $page, filter: $filter, sortBy: $sortBy) {\\n    items {\\n      uuid\\n      title\\n      price\\n      currency\\n      thumbnail\\n      createdAt\\n      state\\n      category {\\n        id\\n        name\\n        engName\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      user {\\n        uuid\\n        displayName\\n        avatar(width: 96, height: 96) {\\n          url\\n          __typename\\n        }\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    trackingInfo {\\n      transactionId\\n      listName\\n      recommenderId\\n      experimentId\\n      variantId\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    totalCount\\n    pageInfo {\\n      startCursor\\n      hasPreviousPage\\n      endCursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n      __typename\\n      }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n","variables":{"page":{"count":36},"filter":{"queryString":null,"category":"2","regionId":null,"attributeFilters":[]},"sortBy":"CREATED_DESC"},"operationName":"ListingsPage"}'

response = requests.post('https://www.tayara.tn/graphql', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.json()['data']['listings']['totalCount'])
```

Comment: I got this  error : `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @user3729357 , it seem that `data` formatting does matter. Try now. Does it work?

Comment: it works but I need to put the result in a variable. When trying to put it in a variable, I got `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @user3729357 , I've just tried and assigning value works fine... Maybe Server not always return the value (e.g. status code is `204`), so you might need to repeat the request in case `response.status_code == 204`

Comment: how to do to extract ads urls existing in the web page ?

Comment: @user3729357 , what do you mean by *ads urls*? Which ads exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to scrape a classified ads website https://www.tayara.tn/sc/immobilier/appartements and I need to have the URL of each ad to scrape it

Comment: @user3729357 , oh, you mean the result list. Links like `https://www.tayara.tn/listings/appartements-2/322763ff-7c7c-4556-9c72-5f0530ca3b08/r%C3%A9sidence-yassine-la-manouba-`?

Comment: @user3729357 , You can get details of each result as `for item in response.json()['data']['listings']['items']: print(item)`. Currently see no links in the same XHR... I will try to check how to get links also, but if it's urgent you might need to post new question

Comment: can u help me please. I am stuck

Comment: @user3729357 , do you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198958/cant-scrape-results-list-urls-from-xhr-call)?

Comment: @user3729357 , I've already checked it, but the logic is seem to be really quite complicated... I'll have look again when I have free time

Comment: I did it using selenium and I have all needed information but the problem was that selenium breaks down in the middle and I can't scrape all ads

Comment: @user3729357 , how does it `breaks down`? Maybe you should post new question regarding Selenium approach? I guess it would be much easier to solve it